# Can't get deque to delete from front

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework assignment right now.  I am supposed to set up a deque which is easy enough, but I'm also supposed to delete from the front, have the array act like a deque.
My problem is that for whatever reason it's not working.  Here's the method I created to delete from the front:

```
public Object deleteFromFront(Object e)
{
    Object[] temp = new Object[capacity];
    for(int i = 1; i < size() - 1; i++){
        temp[i] = A[i+1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size() - 1; i++)
    {
        A[i] = temp[i];
    }
    A = temp;
    return A;
}
```

The thinking is that I create a temp array in which the other array will be moved into it starting at position 1.  As such, it will ignore the first one, thus starting with the second one.  However, whenever I do this, it doesn't seem to be deleting the first.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider `System.arraycopy`. Allocate the new array to be one less than the current, and then start the src at 1, dst at 0. Set the current back to the new one. Be sure to check for no elements at all.

Comment: What's the need for the parameter `Object  e`?

Comment: (since this is a home work) Try Step through debugging using IDE.    Also learn about unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't seem right.

1. What's the use of `Object e`?
2. What is `A`? Is it an array of Object type? Is is declared in the method?

Comment: 1. Object e was just a temporary variable I had there in order to pass something in.  In previous assignments I had noticed that I had to have something there while passing something in, so I figured I might this time.
2. As for A, I should have clarified, that's the deque itself.  I'm not creative, so that's what I went with for the deque name.